# Setting a numerical value to a sum

Tags: matrix

bear with me as I'm very inexperienced with Mathematica, although I think my problem is reasonably straight forward:

I'm currently trying to find a matrix from a simple expression. I've found a way to extract the matrix, however there still remains a constraint that I must somehow impose in order for the matrix to be correct. Here is what I have:

```
nn = 10;
row[n_] := Sum[(p + 1 + R + 3 n^2) a[p], {p, 0, nn - 1}] + \[Alpha] a[n - 1]
vector = Table[a[i], {i, 0, nn - 1}];
matrix = Table[D[row[i], vector[[j]]], {i, 1, nn}, {j, 1, nn}]
```

This produces a matrix which is fantastic. However, I still have two "boundary conditions" left to impose which are (written in Mathematica code):

```
Sum[a[n],{n,0,nn-1}]=0
Sum[n^2a[n],{n,0,nn-1}]=0
```

Does anyone have any ideas of how I can impose these constraints upon the above set of code, such that the end matrix takes them into account?

Thank you :)

Edit:

```
nn = 10;
row[n_] := Sum[(p + 1 + R + 3 n^2) a[p], {p, 0, nn - 1}] + \[Alpha] a[n - 1]
vector = Table[a[i], {i, 0, nn - 1}];
matrix = Table[D[row[i], vector[[j]]], {i, 1, nn}, {j, 1, nn}]
matrix /. { a[0] -> -Sum[i^2 a[i],{i,2,nn-1}] - Sum[a[i],{i,1,nn-1}], a[1] -> -Sum[i^2 a[i],{i,2,nn-1}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use the 2 equations to eliminate 2 of the `a[n]`. E.g. to eliminate `a[0]`and `a[1]`:

From `Sum[a[n],{n,0,nn-1}]=0` and `Sum[n^2a[n],{n,0,nn-1}]=0` we get:

```
a[0]== -Sum[a[i],{i,1,nn-1}]
a[1]== -Sum[i^2 a[i],{i,2,nn-1}]
```

Or:

```
a[0]==  -Sum[i^2 a[i],{i,2,nn-1}] - Sum[a[i],{i,1,nn-1}]
a[1]== -Sum[i^2 a[i],{i,2,nn-1}]
```

To insert this into `matrix`, you can use `ReplaceAll` (/.) and a `Rule` (.. -> ..), look this up in the manual:

```
matrix /. {
  a[0] -> -Sum[i^2 a[i],{i,2,nn-1}] - Sum[a[i],{i,1,nn-1}],
  a[1] -> -Sum[i^2 a[i],{i,2,nn-1}]}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I see, so I can impose these conditions upon the matrix simply by rearranging the constraining sums. How would I go about inserting this into the code?

Comment: I added this to my answer.

Comment: Ah yes, amazing stuff! I've added an edit to my original post which is what I think my code should now look like. Does it look okay? Thank you again for you time, it is greatly appreciated.